# How can I capitalize letters in a ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, laravel-5.3

How can I display my object propertyname in capital letters when working with `ng-repeat`?

I got something like this now:

```
<tr ng-repeat="dossier in dossiers">
    <td>
        <a ng-href="/dossiers/@{{ dossier.id }}">@{{strtoupper(dossier.license_plate)}}</a>
    </td>   
</tr>
```

Comment: you can try filter like {{dossier.license_plate|uppercase}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`uppercase` Angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase):

```
@{{dossier.license_plate | uppercase}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixin PHP and JS code ?

```
<tr ng-repeat="dossier in dossiers">
    <td>
        <a ng-href="/dossiers/@{{ dossier.id }}">@{{dossier.license_plate.toUpperCase()}}</a>
    </td>   
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`uppercase`** filter with angular,

```
 <a ng-href="/dossiers/@{{ dossier.id }}">@{{dossier.license_plate | uppercase }}</a>
```